# Scrapy opened page different than original URL

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, response

I'm trying to scrape price data from a website,

If I just type in http://search.suning.com/iPad/ in the browser and search, the website looks like this:
[image: page opened with URL]

However, with my code, I did

```
start_urls = [
        'https://search.suning.com/{}/'.format('iPad')
    ]
...
open_in_browser(response)
```

and got this page:
[image: Scrapy opened page]

Basically, the price information (which is what I want to scrape) is no longer displayed. I'm not sure why since it should be the exact same link. Any ideas what caused the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: I seem to be getting the same as yourself. Can't seem to get the XPATH for the prices within scrapy shell either. Seems unlikely but is scrapy messing up the encoding and it's ignoring the span ? Would be interested to hear from someone abit more experienced. Sorry I haven't been able to help much!

Comment: the price information comes from JS call, so you need to create the same JS call as website does or use selenium.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Comment: The url is slightly different between the 2 links. One is https which is a secured website, the other is http which is unsecured. I can see prices on one page but not on the other.